# One spider with 2 different URL and 2 parse using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I have 2 different domain with 2 different approach running in one spider I have tried this code but nothing works any idea please?

```
class SalesitemSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'salesitem_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www2.hm.com','www.forever21.com']
    url = ['https://www.forever21.com/eu/shop/Catalog/GetProducts' , 'https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page-size=20']

   #Json Payload code here

    def start_requests(self):
       for i in self.url:
        if (i == 'https://www.forever21.com/eu/shop/Catalog/GetProducts'):
            print("sample: " + i)
            payload = self.payload.copy()
            payload['page']['pageNo'] = 1
            yield scrapy.Request(
            i, method='POST', body=json.dumps(payload),
            headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
            callback=self.parse_2, meta={'pageNo': 1})

        if (i == 'https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page-size=20'):
            yield scrapy.Request(i, callback=self.parse_1)

    def parse_1(self, response):
     #Some code of getting item 

    def parse_2(self, response):
     data = json.loads(response.text)
        for product in data['CatalogProducts']:
            item = GpdealsSpiderItem_f21()
         #item yield

        yield item

        # simulate pagination if we are not at the end
        if len(data['CatalogProducts']) == self.payload['page']['pageSize']:
            payload = self.payload.copy()
            payload['page']['pageNo'] = response.meta['pageNo'] + 1
            yield scrapy.Request(
              self.url, method='POST', body=json.dumps(payload),
             headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
               callback=self.parse_2, meta={'pageNo': payload['page']['pageNo']}
           )
```

I just always have this problem

NameError: name 'url' is not defined

Comment: Yeah I forgot @ThiagoCurvelo Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different spiders in the same class. For the sake of maintainability, I recommend you to keep them in different files.

If you really want to keep them together, it would be easier split the urls into two lists:

```py
type1_urls = ['https://www.forever21.com/eu/shop/Catalog/GetProducts', ]
type2_urls = ['https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page-size=20', ]

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.type1_urls:
        payload = self.payload.copy()
        yield Request(
            # ...
            callback=self.parse_1
       )

    for url in self.type2_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `self.url` in `for` cycle and then work with `i` variable inside your loop for comparison, request yielding, etc.:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for i in self.url:
        if (i == 'https://www.forever21.com/eu/shop/Catalog/GetProducts'):
            payload = self.payload.copy()
            payload['page']['pageNo'] = 1
            yield scrapy.Request(
                i, method='POST', body=json.dumps(payload),
                headers={'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
                callback=self.parse_2, meta={'pageNo': 1})

        if (i == 'https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page-size=20'):
            yield scrapy.Request(i, callback=self.parse_1)
```

Comment: Hi @vezunchik, thank you for helping me after I tried your code I got this error "Request url must be str or unicode, got list:" any idea please? Thank you

Comment: Check your code, you call `yield scrapy.Request(self.url, ...`. Check my code, I call `yield scrapy.Request(i, ...`. Check and update all variables inside loop.

Comment: Hi @vezunchik I still can't figure it out, can you help me on this one please thank you so much, stuck for almost a day. :(

Comment: In first `if` you call `yield scrapy.Request` with `self.url`. It is a list, that's why it raises an error. Replace it with `i`, loop variable. And check other variables carefully.

Comment: Hi vezunchik I understand it now, but it seems the problem is in def parse_2 i don't know but it seems the problem is still in the url. I've edited my code so that the helper can see the problem too

Comment: Please, check again, the same problem in your `parse_2` function.